# Handling refunds of an in-app purchase with iTunes

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect

I work for a company offering in-app purchases. I am trying to have our purchase statistics alright after a user has obtained a refund for an in-app purchase with iTunes connect.

I have read the [`iTunes connect sales and trends guide (pdf)`](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf) and know how to retrieve sales for a given period of time with the auto-ingestion tool provided.

Unfortunately, the report I get does not contain any field that would allow me to know precisely which purchase or user was refunded. I just know about the amount and Apple id, so here comes my question:

- Is there a way to add custom fields when creating a new in-app purchase so that I could pass my order_id to be retrieved it in the sales report?

That is the only way I see to know exactly which purchase on our side was refunded.
Thank you in advance!